# "Исполнение" и "старческий хор", или Где заканчивается придаточное?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, придаточное-предложение

> Исполнение монашенками древних церковных гимнов внутри чрева этого
>   средневекового гулкого чудовища, когда уходящее солнце заливает лучами
>   престол и старческий хор, в котором лидируют несколько юных, светлых
>   голосов, – завораживает.

Завораживает, как я понимаю, исполнение. Как быть со старческим хором - он присуседился...

Comment: Ввиду развесистости конструкции, нужно прямое _напоминание_, к чему относится последнее слово: " - _всё это_ завораживает". Либо можно "монашенок" убрать из начала и вместо "старческого" написать "хор монашенок"
Хор мог бы быть "старушечьим" - в отличие от "старческого" (это совершенно недопустимо), это сочетается не только со свойственными возрасту болезнями, а и с мероприятиями, в которых участвуют старушки - напр. есть устойчивовое сочетание "старушечьи посиделки", встречается во многих книгах.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что мысли у автора путаются. В реальности гимны исполняет хор монашек-старушек, в котором лидируют несколько юных голосов. И этот хор залит лучами солнца  А у автора мысль разорвана на куски: гимны исполняет хор монашек — отдельно, а солнце освещет хор струшек, в котором лидируют несколько юных голосов, — отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Исполнение монашенками древних церковных гимнов внутри чрева этого средневекового гулкого чудовища, (когда уходящее солнце заливает лучами престол и старческий хор), (в котором лидируют несколько юных, светлых голосов), – завораживает].*

Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными, соединёнными последовательно, которые находятся внутри главного.  Тире как бы расставляет акценты, выделяя сказуемое и обращая на него внимание. Всё нормально, такое бывает.

Исполнение завораживает, когда солнце заливает старческий хор, в котором  лидируют несколько юных голосов.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, требуется редактирование, но при этом надо понять мысль автора и не исказить ее. Что его завораживает? Во-первых, место действия (древнее помещение, залитое уходящим солнцем), а во-вторых, само действие (старческий хор, перемешанный с юными голосами, это впечатляет, наверное).

Тогда можно предложить вариант по схеме: исполнение гимнов в древнем помещении  и сам необычный хор завораживают.

**Исполнение** монашенками древних церковных гимнов **внутри** чрева этого средневекового гулкого чудовища, **когда** уходящее солнце заливает лучами престол, **и старческий хор**, в котором лидируют несколько юных, светлых голосов, – **завораживают**.

Тире **интонационное**, проясняет структуру предложения.

Comment: Исполнение монашенками и хор из тех же монашенок  завораживают?! Как-то коряво.

Comment: Завораживает НЕОБЫЧНОЕ. Смешение времён, например, когда    в обыденном и материальном  видишь нечто символическое. Трудно сказать, что действительно хотел сказать автор. Но в том, что сказал, я ничего завораживающего не вижу, форма абсолютно не отражает подобного содержания. Вот я читаю предложение: солнце заливает лучами престол и старческий хор...Эти слова абсолютно не гармонируют друг с другом,  так что мне кажется, что они даже пытаются отодвинуться  друг от друга подальше. И это вы (и не только вы) считаете нормальным, это не коряво?

Comment: В действительности в изображенной ситуации, вероятно,  присутствовало какое-то "волшебство", но где тот художник, который это почувствует,  и подберет нужные краски-слова, и составит из них целостную и всем понятную картину.